# Recursive statement with dividing the column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

I have a table called "srt_shipped_tools" with the some columns like below mentioned image:

[image: shipped_tools]

Take the first row in the above table. We see Partpath column, in the partpath column we have multiple ids by separating with "/" the last separated(0010-36299) value is child of (0010-81717) and (0010-81717) value is child of (0241-07133) so on.

Expected result: the partpath value should split with "/" and the output should be like the image attached.

[image]

I tried a CTE expression by using recursion, but it is not working for me.

I tried the with the below query with the recursion technique, but it is not working as expected.

```
;WITH Numbers AS (
    SELECT Partpath, partno, parentpartno, slot_num, consumptionenditem, plant
    FROM srt_shipped_tools
    WHERE slot_num = '901013' and PARTNO = '0015-08223' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.Partpath, a.partno, a.parentpartno, a.slot_num, a.consumptionenditem, a.plant
    FROM srt_shipped_tools a 
    INNER JOIN Numbers b on a.slot_num = b.slot_num and a.plant =b.plant and a.consumptionenditem = b.consumptionenditem and a.parentpartno = b.partno 
    WHERE a.slot_num = '901013' and a.PARTNO = '0015-08223'
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbers
WHERE slot_num = '901013' and PARTNO = '0015-08223'
```

Comment: You can use [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it can give you your desired result

Comment: You need to specify the version of SQL Server for these types of questions as the answer would heavily depend on it. `STRING_SPLIT()` function is a recent addition and makes the query rather simple.

Comment: Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: You have enough rep to know how to do it: edit tags in your question please. :)

Comment: I used STRING_SPLIT(), but unable to use properly and unable to get proper result

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: yaa, let me do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using string_split your query would be:

```
 SELECT value,Partpath, partno, parentpartno, slot_num, consumptionenditem, plant
 FROM srt_shipped_tools
 CROSS APPLY string_split(Partpath,'/')
 WHERE slot_num = '901013' and PARTNO = '0015-08223'
```

You can order by the index of `value` in the `Partpath`:

```
SELECT value,Partpath, partno, parentpartno, slot_num, consumptionenditem, plant
 FROM srt_shipped_tools
 CROSS APPLY string_split(Partpath,'/')
 WHERE slot_num = '901013' and PARTNO = '0015-08223' 
 ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value, Partpath) DESC
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. The above query works like the parent will come from first but it should come from last.

Comment: @SivamohanReddy you can test the new code i added in the aswer.

Comment: I modified screenshots, could you check and help me the query

Comment: i didn't understand why for `parentpartno = 0010-36299` you select all partPaths but for the other you don't, is it because you didn't copy all the desired result or you want details for on that `parentpartno`.

Comment: we can remove that parentpartno = 0010-36299, it is for getting less amount of records, but i'm little confused that is it giving any problem to put where condition?